# Spark: Filtering based on property files

Tags: scala

I have numerous number of files in a folder and among them I need to only process few files based on ***file_types and portfolios***.
Filenaming pattern looks like below for the files.

```
/* FILENAME pattern */ 
<file_name>_<file_type>_<portfolio>_<date>_<time>.csv

<Code>
val data = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(wholeFilesPath)
val files = data.map { case (individualFile, _) => individualFile}
files.collect.foreach( file => {
                           f => /* code */
                   })
```

What I am looking at it, is a way where i can store my the ***file_types and portfolios*** in a property file outside of my coding logics
and filter the files based on that. 
In case in future if I need to add or remove any portfolios I want to do it only in the property file.
How do I proceed with this?

Comment: How is that related to Spark? What would change if you used some other Scala library?

Comment: @@Jacek, Ok np, I have removed the tags for spark. But I don't understand what's your second question is? Guide me please

Comment: I can't understand how your question is related to Spark (other than that the example uses it).

Comment: @@Jacek, Thank you! I got your point. Lesson learnt for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use properties files if you are sending that properties file with your `spark-submit` command. In you code you should do something like this

```
import java.util.Properties

def foo(Proerties:properties): DataFrame = {
  val a =  properties.getProperty("mykey")
  val b = spark.read.json(a)
  return a
}
```

Your properties file would look something like this:

```
mykey= bar_portfoliocode.csv
```

Comment: @@, Thank you user2315840!!